# How to call http request on every page entering in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, routes, state, reload

how can I get a new http response every time if I come back to the Home-tab?

I tried several things. I read about "$state.reload()", but I don't know where to use it. ng-click doesn't work in tabs.html.

Controller:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        'use strict';

// how to call this every time on coming back to this tab?
        $http.get("api.php")
            .then(function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.plan = response.data;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.error("Failed HTTP get: " + response.status + " " + response.data);
            });
// ...
```

tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab title="Home" href="#/tab/home">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-home"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
<!-- ... -->
</ion-tabs>
```

index.html:

```
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

module:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider

        .state('tab', {
            url: '/tab',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
        })

        .state('tab.home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                'tab-home': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-home.html',
                    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: look at `angular.run`, and there subscribe to `stateChangeStart`, make the request there.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller

```
$scope.loadHttp = function(){
        $http.get("api.php")
            .then(function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.plan = response.data;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.error("Failed HTTP get: " + response.status + " " + response.data);
            });

};
```

In view for example

```
<div ng-click ="loadHttp()">Tab</div>
```

Comment: because you don't specify controller for your tab state.

Comment: .state('tab', {
                url: '/tab',
                abstract: true,
                controller: 'TabCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
            })

Comment: <ion-tab title="Vertretungsplan" icon-off="ion-ios-calendar-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-calendar" href="#/tab/home" on-select="test()">

Comment: .controller('TabCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
        $scope.test = function () {
            alert("test");
            $state.reload();
        }
    });

Comment: create child state for your home/tab maybe?

Answer (score 0):

User on-Select.

```
<ion-tab
  title="Home"
  icon="my-icon"
  href="#/tab/home"
  on-select="onTabSelected()"
  on-deselect="onTabDeselected()">
</ion-tab>
```

Here is [Demo](http://play.ionic.io/app/44e768d78490)

Comment: Do I have to delete tabs.html and write anything in index.html?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work now. Thanks to @praHoc.

I added "cache" three times, nothing else.

```
        .state('tab', {
            url: '/tab',
            abstract: true,
            cache: false,
            templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
        })

        // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

        .state('tab.home', {
            url: '/home',
            cache: false,
            views: {
                'tab-home': {
                    cache: false,
                    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-home.html',
                    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                }
            }
        })
```